# Excel formula to find the first non-alpha character in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way using a cell formula in Excel to find the index of the first non-alpha character in a referenced cell?

I've imported data into Excel which has a column that looks like this:

`<some text I don't want in the derived cell><some text that prepends the text I want and is always constant>TheTextIWant<Some non-alpha character><some other characters that may be alpha or not>`

I'm trying to create a formula that so far looks like this:

`=MID(<cell reference>, SEARCH("<prepended text>, <cell reference>) + <length of prepended text>, ??)`

Where ?? is some sub-formula that finds the first non-alpha character after "TheTextIWant"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To go into a bit more detail about how the array formula works (@Jacob's formula seems to be slightly wrong in a couple of cases, e.g. 0 for "A1A"), so here's what I think is a working version, expanded for ease of reading. Please let me know of any examples where it doesn't work.

```
=IF(
    LEN(A1)=0
    ,0
    ,MIN(
        IF(
            ISNUMBER(
                1*MID(
                    A1,
                    ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),
                    1
                )
            ),
            ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),
            LEN(A1)+1
        )
    )
)
```

1. At the heart of this is the row() function, which in array mode is evaluated once for each of the cells in the range a1:a*n*, where *n* is the length of the string in cell A1, creating an array {1,2,...,*n*}.
2. The array is passed to the MID function, which in turn produces an array {*char_1*,*char_2*,...,*char_n*}.
3. The array is multiplied by 1 to prevent numeric characters being parsed as text in subsequent steps. This could also be done using VALUE().
4. It is then passed to the ISNUMBER() function, which outputs an array of logical values.

This is the array of *conditions* passed to IF. A second array is then constructed by repeating step 1, containing the position of each character. The IF function, in array mode, produces an array of outputs. Cases whose condition is TRUE are set to the corresponding value from the array of character positions, and the rest are all set to LEN(A1)+1 so they are larger than any possible position values for any numeric characters.

The MIN function then evaluates the array output by IF, returning the smallest value, which is the position of the first numeric character in the string in cell A1. The outermost IF function forces the formula to return 0 if there is no text in the cell, rather than 1; otherwise, INDIRECT returns a #REF! error when searching for cell A0, which propagates upwards, and the FALSE condition is returned by IF, returning 0 + 1 = 1.

To search for the position of the first non-numeric character instead, all you have to do is reverse the order of the second 2 arguments to IF:

```
=IF(
    LEN(A1)=0
    ,0
    ,MIN(
        IF(
            ISNUMBER(
                1*MID(
                    A1,
                    ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),
                    1
                )
            ),
            LEN(A1)+1,
            ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1)))

        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[On this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringformulas.aspx) there is an array formula for finding the "Position Of First Digit In A String."  You should be able to modify that to use the 'T' function (to determine if a character is text), incorporate a little subtraction and then get to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I will try to take a look at this this weekend. -rp

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around array formulas as described in the article.  More study is needed...

Comment: It's not just you- the formula works, but when evaluated step-by-step it crashes excel!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula extracts numbers from the string , similar way can be used to extract non alpha characters , just place the characters required instead of the numbers in the bracket

```
=RIGHT(D3,LEN(D3)+1-MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,9},D3&"0123456789")))
```