# excel separate text and numbers

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

This is an excel problem. I need to separate text and numbers in a string. The string can start with numbers or can start with characters. There could be spaces in between text or numbers. So the formula needs to be versatile enough to separate it into 2 columns with one column consisting of only text and the other only numbers. Please help.

Thank you very much

Examples of text strings

- 07 7878 8788 ABC JKSDKJK
- ABCVG HDH 656688
- AGSGD89789798798
- 798 99AJSUDFK

Comment: you could use some nested version of replace() to replace all the numbers with "", basically removing them and leaving only the letters.

Comment: I tried using formulae like
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"))-1))

Answer (score 1):

***Only Text***

Function Alphas(ByVal strInString As String) As String
Dim lngLen As Long, strOut As String
Dim i As Long, strTmp As String

```
lngLen = Len(strInString)
strOut = ""
For i = 1 To lngLen
    strTmp = Left$(strInString, 1)
    strInString = Right$(strInString, lngLen - i)
    'The next statement will extract BOTH Lower and Upper case chars
    If (Asc(strTmp) >= 65 And Asc(strTmp) <= 90 Or Asc(strTmp) >= 97 And Asc(strTmp) <= 122) Then
        'to extract just lower case, use the limit 97 - 122
        'to extract just upper case, use the limit 65 - 90
        strOut = strOut & strTmp
    End If
Next i
Alphas = strOut
```

End Function

Only Numbers

Function Numerics(ByVal strInString As String) As String
Dim lngLen As Long, strOut As String
Dim i As Long, strTmp As String

```
lngLen = Len(strInString)
strOut = ""
For i = 1 To lngLen
    strTmp = Left$(strInString, 1)
    strInString = Right$(strInString, lngLen - i)
    If (Asc(strTmp) >= 48 And Asc(strTmp) <= 57) Then
        strOut = strOut & strTmp
    End If
Next i
Numerics = strOut
```

End Function

***Only Number & Text***

Function Alphanumerics(ByVal strInString As String) As String
Dim lngLen As Long, strOut As String
Dim i As Long, strTmp As String

```
lngLen = Len(strInString)
strOut = ""
For i = 1 To lngLen
    strTmp = Left$(strInString, 1)
    strInString = Right$(strInString, lngLen - i)
    'The next statement will extract BOTH Lower and Upper case chars
    If (Asc(strTmp) >= 65 And Asc(strTmp) <= 90 Or Asc(strTmp) >= 97 And Asc(strTmp) <= 122 or Asc(strTmp) >= 48 And Asc(strTmp) <= 57) Then
        'to extract just lower case, use the limit 97 - 122
        'to extract just upper case, use the limit 65 - 90
        strOut = strOut & strTmp
    End If
Next i
Alphanumerics = strOut
```

End Function

This can use in excel too but this is modified by me for Access use

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your cells in column A are of the form {numbers + spaces}{non-numeric text} or the reverse, you can start by finding the positions of the first numeric character and the first non-numeric, non-space character in each cell. You could then use those plus a bit of extra logic to extract the appropriate substrings using `MID`.

I posted array formulas to do this here:
[Excel formula to find the first non-alpha character in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506467/excel-formula-to-find-the-first-non-alpha-character-in-a-cell)

You would need to make a slight modification to the second formula, so it returns the position of the first character that isn't a number or a space:

```
=MIN(
        IF(
                  1*ISNUMBER(
                  1*MID(
                      A1,
                      ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),
                      1
                  )
                ) +
                1*(MID(
                      A1,
                      ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),
                      1
                  )=" "),
            LEN(A1)+1,
            ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1)))

        )
    )
```